# The debugging mode doesn't active in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I want to test an application, but I got a problem with my device. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 which version is 4.1 (Jelly Bean), and a S. Galaxy Note 8.0 and this is what I have done:

1. I have activated the developer mode.
2. I have activated the USB debugging.
3. I have installed the **ADB** on my computer.

And the problem is that when I connect the phone (or the tablet) to the computer through USB port, the device start in multimedia mode and the debugging mode doesn't active.

I hope that you can help me, thanks.

Comment: May ask you, what does depuration mode mean?

Comment: Sorry, is debugging mode :)

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: My operating system is Windows 7

Comment: Is your PC detecting phone ?? check in device manager .If not U need to install correct drivers!!

Comment: Yes, my PC recognize it like a multimedia device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download sansung driver for windows 7. Try this http://www.usb-drivers.org/samsung-android-usb-device-driver.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this is the message that I got: "Windows determines that the driver software for your device is updated" :/